# Obtaining a lists of artists using cocoalibspotify for iOS

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'd like to quickly get a list of artist names in a user's "library" or playlists. Is there an easy / asynchronous way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the example project "Guess the Intro" included with CocoaLibSpotify. The method `waitAndFillTrackPool` in that project shows how to get a list of all the tracks in the user's playlists.

Once you have that list, you can do the following to get the artists from them, put them through a set to thin out duplicates, then wait until they're loaded.

```
NSArray *artists = [theTrackPool valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.artists"];
NSArray *uniqueArtists = [[NSSet setWithArray:artists] allObjects];

[SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:uniqueArtists then:^(NSArray *loadedArtists) {
    // Artists are loaded!
    // Log a list of artist names...
    NSLog(@"%@", [loadedArtists valueForKey:@"name"]);
}];
```

Comment: I'm noticing in the guess the intro app and when I implement it myself that the initial 'then' block returns only 2 playlists (and 5 tracks). When I close the app and reopen it, the second time around waitAndFillTrackPool gives all 6 playlist and a lot more tracks. Any reason?

Comment: Can I get all tracks when using SPAsyncLoading the first time?

Comment: Yes - read the documentation to [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:timeout:then:]. You need to increase the timeout.