# Spotify Track List

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, spotify

All!

...    I've `integrated Spotify` in my app using Sample Spotify Examples. I'm `able to play track` with Spotify's default controller.Now what my problem is: currently I'm able to play only one track. What to do if I want see the `entire playlist track`?

Thanking You in advance

Answer (score 1):

With the current API, you need to do this yourself. I don't know exactly how you're doing playback, but when the current track ends you should prepare the next track and play it. There's no "play this list" API built-in to CocoaLibSpotify at the moment.

Comment: I don't want to play entire track. I just want my user to see the whole track list available with my spotify account.But anyways I got my answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10727246/1538079 . Thanking you for giving that solution.